# Rails how to modify instance's values in methods from Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an object instance in my UserController as such

```
@user = User.new
```

and I'm trying to call a method from User model like that

```
def update

    @user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(user_params)

        @user.update_age

        format.html { redirect_to @user}#, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, notice: 'Update unsuccessful' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And here's the method itself:

```
def update_age
    self.age = 50
end
```

As the result the value remains the same and does not change. How can I access the @user instance from the controller in the User model and modify its values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to update the age separately from the model instead of `update_attributes` method then in the model method you would have to call `save` on the object so that the changes are persisted.

```
def update_age
    self.age = 50
    self.save
end
```

Doesn't `@user.update_attributes(user_params)` already update the age of the user. Check your `user_params` to verify that age is permitted as a parameter. Is the `@user.update_attributes(user_params)` throwing any errors ?

Comment: @AlexanderDonets - please check the updated answer also.

Comment: Oh it does update it, I just created "update_age" method as an example. I have many other methods in my model that need to save the state of the instance.